# How to add some CSS/html5 effects to give it the illusion of it being fiery?

Tags: css, html, animation, visual-effects

I have just been trying out and sort of learning bits and bobs in html5. I basically have this little animation: http://jsfiddle.net/Hazza/dJgC9/4/ It is just some images falling out the sky repeatedly. Fun. I was just wondering if there was some way to make them look a bit more exciting. They are supposed to be meteors, or something. So I was looking to try and add the illusion of fire to them. I thought I could have a few different images with different CSS effects like blur and load them randomly as they fall. But it looked...yeah. Retarded. This was kinda the effect I was going for: http://gw2101.gtm.guildwars2.com/en/ . That is flash. And looks fancy as.

Is this at all possible do you think? Or is it something best left to photoshop and then alternate between a few different images? I suck at photoshopping. :D

Anyway I was just playing around for a bit of fun. I'm already secretly proud of my terribad little firestorm but hey, it's a start. Thanks for any input or insight.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, my friend. http://mentadreams.com/2011/03/fire-effect-with-css3/